# perform function after inserting every row from select

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. first table has data

```
Table_1
===================

ID | Name | Status       | Code
-------------------------------------
1  | John | Manager      | A
2  | Don  | Manager      | A
2  | Don  | Supervisor   | B
3  | Jim  | Manager      | A
3  | Jim  | Supervisor   | B
3  | Jim  | Employee     | C
```

Now I have another table where I want to move this data so I used Insert from select statement but in the table Table_2 , I want each Name to have all three status( manager, supervisor, employee)

If a name in table_1 already has all 3 status and code then it should insert from select without any change, but If it has only 1 status then table_2 should insert two more dummy names with the same id AND if if a name has two entry then enter only 1 dummy name with same ID.

Here is the Table_2 which I actually want:

```
 Table_2
 ===================

 ID | Name | Status       | Code
 -------------------------------------
 1  | John | Manager      | A
 1  | Dum1 | Supervisor   | B
 1  | Dum2 | Employee     | C
 2  | Don  | Manager      | A
 2  | Don  | Supervisor   | B
 2  | Dum2 | Employee     | C
 3  | Jim  | Manager      | A
 3  | Jim  | Supervisor   | B
 3  | Jim  | Employee     | C
```

I am using Insert from select statement but that simply copies the data form table_1 to table_2

Comment: Your first table is going to cause you grief here because you have no primary key. The ID values are duplicated.

Comment: It is going be duplicated that is why I haven't given any primary key to this.

Comment: You still should have a primary key. Otherwise you have a heap which is a performance nightmare. A composite key of ID and Code might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the biggest issue here is that your data is not normalized. This causes lots of challenges. There is probably an easier way to accomplish this but here is what I came up with. The first step is to use a couple of ctes to make your data normalized so you can easily join to it. From there a simple ROW_NUMBER will get you Dummy_1 etc that will restart for each value of ID and will always be in sequence regardless of which position in the ID the missing data is.

Using the fine sample data and table from scsimon I put this together.

```
declare @table1 table (ID int, Name varchar(64), status varchar(64), Code char(1))
insert into @table1
values
(1,'John','Manager','A'),
(2,'Don','Manager','A'),
(2,'Don','Supervisor','B'),
(3,'Jim','Manager','A'),
(3,'Jim','Supervisor','B'),
(3,'Jim','Employee','C')
;

with Codes as
(
    select distinct Code
        , Status
    from @table1
)
, IDs as
(
    select distinct ID
    from @table1
)
select i.ID
    , Name = case when t.Name is null then 'Dummy_' + convert(varchar(10), row_number() over(partition by i.ID, t.Name order by c.Code)) else t.Name end
    , c.Status
    , c.Code
from Codes c
cross join IDs i
left join @table1 t on t.code = c.Code and t.ID = i.ID
order by i.ID
    , c.Code
```

Comment: Not sure about better, just a different approach to a poor design.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a table constructor and `cross apply`.

```
declare @table1 table (ID int, Name varchar(64), status varchar(64), Code char(1))
insert into @table1
values
(1,'John','Manager','A'),
(2,'Don','Manager','A'),
(2,'Don','Supervisor','B'),
(3,'Jim','Manager','A'),
(3,'Jim','Supervisor','B'),
(3,'Jim','Employee','C')



declare @table2 table (ID int, Name varchar(64), status varchar(64), Code char(1))

insert into @table2 (ID, Name, Status, Code)
select distinct
    ID
    ,Name
    ,x.Status
    ,Code = case 
                when x.Status = 'Manager' then 'A'
                when x.Status = 'Supervisor' then 'B'
                when x.Status = 'Employee' then 'C'
            end
from @table1
cross apply (values('Manager'),('Supervisor'),('Employee')) x(Status)
order by
    ID
    ,x.Status


update t2
    set t2.Name = 'Dummy_' + case 
                                when t2.Status =  'Manager' then '1'
                                when t2.Status =  'Supervisor' then '2'
                                when t2.Status =  'Employee' then '3'
                            end
from
    @table2 t2
left join
    @table1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Code = t2.Code
where
    t1.ID is null



select *
from @table2
order by ID, Code
```

Comment: i have many values in my table_1, do I need to manually copy those value to constructor @table1 or i can use insert from select ?

Comment: He is using a table variable here instead of a real table. In your case just pull from table_1. You also probably need to add distinct so you don't get duplicate rows when they exist in your data already.

Comment: I jsut read your question more closely... i don't insert "Dummy" names here, but you could easily adjust or update the table if need be. I'm not sure if that was a real requirement or not. If you really want the name to not be the same for each ID (which seems odd) let me know.

Comment: I actually want Dummy names, which I will define as Dummy_1 and Dummy_2

Comment: It worked but I didn't understand the update statement, it will be great if you can explain that. And I will write a stored proc for this so Do I need to put insert and update statement right after each other ?

Comment: The update just changes the name to Dummy_1/2/3 based on the status. It ONLY updates rows that were not in the original table, i.e. table1. And yes, update would need to come after the insert. I would use @SeanLange code though, it's more dynamic